# Where does the apostrophe go within a dialogue if the word ends with a possessive plural word?

Tags: possessives

I've been wracking my brain and fingers googling this, but no site has an example, so here I am. Where does the apostrophe go within a dialogue if the word ends with a possessive plural? Does it go after "parents" or after the period of "parents"?

Which example below is correct? 1 or 2?

"And the apartment?" she asked.

1. He replied, “My parents.’”
2. He replied, “My parents’.”

Comment: I don't understand why this is problematic. The apostrophe is attached to the word, so it's part of the sentence. The period/full stop marks the end of the sentence, so it goes last of all.

Answer (score 3):

[Kate Bunting is correct](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/610115/where-does-the-apostrophe-go-within-a-dialogue-if-the-word-ends-with-a-possessiv#comment1544041_610115): the apostrophe is attached to the word, so (2) is correct:

> He replied, “My parents’.”

You may be confusing this apostrophe with reported speech and multiple sets of quotation marks, where they can end up together. In this example, the “internal quotation” ends at the same place as what Alonso actually said:

> Alonso said, “Peter told me, ‘You are Alonso.’”